# DateTime.Now not using server time zone for some reason, can anyone speculate as to why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a .net mvc 5 site hosted in Australia which seems to be getting UK time from DateTime.Now instead of Australian time despite running on an Australian server which has Australian time as the local time for the machine.  We are in the UK and the site is published from the UK but I can't seem to discover why DateTime.Now is getting UK time on an Australian server with Australian time.

From what I've read by default DateTime.Now should just use the servers time zone.  Can anyone speculate what could be stopping it from doing so?  There doesn't appear to be any setting in the application doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the timezone is set to UTC in the server config. Try changing the timezone.

Comment: Whereabouts in the server configuration?  I can't see anything, any ideas?  Server manager shows UTC + 10 which is correct.

Comment: What does `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName` return?

Comment: AUS Eastern Standard Time which is the time zone it should be.

Comment: Nevermind, situation resolved, it was only the login time that was being recorded in UTC as it turns out and that was because it called an extension that happened to use DateTime.UTCNow for no apparent reason instead of DateTime.Now.  Have some upvotes for helping me along the way.